# Windows Error LiveKernelEvent code 141 on mostly new parts

Tags: windows-10, crash, windows-error-reporting

My PC specs are as follows:

- Sapphire Pulse RX 560
- AMD FX-8320 with an aftermarket cooler
- 16GB of DDR3 G. Skill RAM
- ASRock 970 Extreme3 motherboard
- Windows 10 64-bit OS
- Thermaltake TR2 700w PSU

I was playing GTA V and the following crash occured:

- "Description
- A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.
- Problem signature
- Problem Event Name:   LiveKernelEvent
- Code: 141
- Parameter 1:  ffff918292a7d010
- Parameter 2:  fffff8003c60f9cc
- Parameter 3:  0
- Parameter 4:  c10
- OS version:   10_0_16299
- Service Pack: 0_0
- Product:  768_1
- OS Version:   10.0.16299.2.0.0.768.101
- Locale ID:    4105"

Many people are saying this is a GPU problem. I bought the GPU in the summer of last year, so the card is not very old. I thought it was a motherboard problem, and I was having other problems with my old board, so I bought a new motherboard. It seemed to fix the problem for most of the time, but occasionally I will get this crash (my old mobo experienced this crash a lot more). Could it possibly be a PSU problem? It is one of the components, besides my CPU, that have been in my PC since I built it ~3-4 years ago.

Thanks for any possible input or help you can provide.

Comment: analyze the dumps with windbg: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons why you're having this issue is due to video card driver failure. The first step would be to install the newest driver, (by completely removing the current driver, and installing the newest driver available). If it continues to malfunction after an update, revert to a much older driver as some new drivers are somewhat buggy. If changing video driver versions does not help, the next step would be to make sure the card is not overheating. You can download cpu-z and gpu-z (both free) to keep an eye on the video card temps.

You may also want to try running a GPU stress test you can download FurMark  (free) Run the test until the GPU temperature maxes out - or until you start having problems (whichever comes first)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same worries until last night. The problem was solved when I updated the motherboard BIOS, so think about checking this- especially with Windows 10.